# Problema con recursividad en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente función en `PHP` que recibe una fecha y un `id_persona`, la cual busca en una tabla de la base de datos si ya existe un registro  con esa fecha y con ese `id_persona`. Funciona bien, solo que necesito que sea recursiva y cuando la llamo nuevamente en caso de que entre al `if` debe cambiar la fecha.

Le sumo un día y la mando a la función `devuelve_fecha_q()` pero ahora esa fecha que recibí la tengo que volver a verificar y vuelvo a llamar a la función y me manda error de sintaxis.

Si comento la línea donde vuelvo a llamar a la función, trabaja bien y me regresa la fecha modificada.

Por ejemplo tengo `2017-02-15` y esa fecha existe, entonces me regresa `2017-02-28` y termina pero necesito que esa última fecha igual la verifique y así n veces hasta que no encuentre registro con la fecha, entonces ya finalizaría y me regresaría la fecha.

```
protected function verifica_fecha_nomina ($id_persona,$fecha_a_verificar) {
    $sql_verifica_nomina = "SELECT DISTINCT
        pn.fecha_fin
            FROM
                personal_nomina_detalle pnd
            INNER JOIN
                personal_nomina pn ON pn.id_nomina = pnd.id_nomina
            WHERE
                pnd.id_persona = $id_persona AND pn.fecha_fin = '$fecha_a_verificar'";

    $res_verifica_nomina = mysql_query($sql_verifica_nomina)or die("¡Error al obtener la fecha verificación nomina! $sql_verifica_nomina".mysql_error());
    $respuesta_verifica_nomina = mysql_num_rows($res_verifica_nomina);

    if ($respuesta_verifica_nomina > 0 && $respuesta_verifica_nomina !== null && $respuesta_verifica_nomina !== '') {
        $fecha_a_verificar = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_a_verificar."+ 1 days"));
        $fecha_a_verificar = devuelve_fecha_q($fecha_a_verificar);
        verifica_fecha_nomina($id_persona,$fecha_a_verificar);
        // echo "El numero de registros con esa fecha es: ".$respuesta_verifica_nomina.$fecha_a_verificar;
    }

    return $fecha_a_verificar;

}
```

**Error en firebug:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y cuál es el error que sale?

Comment: En el firebug me marca error 500 en el archivo de PHP es error de sintaxis, no se que estoy haciendo mal con la recursividad.

Comment: Error 500 no significa error de sintaxis, significa error interno del servidor, las cosas que se me ocurren es que tu recursividad no se acerque a un caso base y por tanto sea infinita, en tal caso te acabas la memoria interna del servidor y se bota. necesitaría mas información.

Comment: puedes pegar el error que te sale para darnos una mejor idea?

Comment: Concuerdo con @Luis estoy seguro que debes darle un límite porque tu ciclo nunca terminará si no encuentra la fecha...

Comment: Configura PHP para que muestre los errores. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13402590/6658955 Luego te darás cuenta cual es el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les comento que ya encontré mi error. Era algo muy tonto. Como estoy utilizando clases olvidé utilizar la pseudovariable `$this` por lo cual se perdía la referencia a las variables. Mi código quedó así:

```
protected function verifica_fecha_nomina ($id_persona, $fecha_a_verificar) {

    $sql_verifica_nomina = "SELECT DISTINCT
        pn.fecha_fin
            FROM
                personal_nomina_detalle pnd
            INNER JOIN
                personal_nomina pn ON pn.id_nomina = pnd.id_nomina
            WHERE
                pnd.id_persona = $id_persona AND pn.fecha_fin = '$fecha_a_verificar'";

      $res_verifica_nomina = mysql_query($sql_verifica_nomina)or die("¡Error al obtener la fecha verificación nomina! $sql_verifica_nomina".mysql_error());
      $respuesta_verifica_nomina = mysql_num_rows($res_verifica_nomina);

      if ($respuesta_verifica_nomina > 0 && $respuesta_verifica_nomina !== null && $respuesta_verifica_nomina !== '') {
          $fecha_a_verificar = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecha_a_verificar."+ 1 days"));
          $fecha_a_verificar = devuelve_fecha_q($fecha_a_verificar);
          $fecha_a_verificar = $this->verifica_fecha_nomina($id_persona,$fecha_a_verificar);
          // echo "El numero de registros con esa fecha es: ".$respuesta_verifica_nomina.$fecha_a_verificar;
      }

      return $fecha_a_verificar;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Siento que tu error es que no cambias la fecha al momento de entrar en la recursividad, por lo que siempre es la misma fecha y el bucle es infinito, tienes que cambiarla de la siguiente forma

```
if ($respuesta_verifica_nomina>0 && $respuesta_verifica_nomina!==null && $respuesta_verifica_nomina!==''){
    $fecha_a_verificar = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecha_a_verificar."+ 1 days"));
    $fecha_a_verificar = devuelve_fecha_q($fecha_a_verificar);
    $fecha_a_verificar = verifica_fecha_nomina($id_persona,$fecha_a_verificar);
    // echo "El numero de registros con esa fecha es: ".$respuesta_verifica_nomina.$fecha_a_verificar;
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero lo intente y sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado.